# Angular server side rendering using angular universal not working with lazy loading module

Tags: angular, angular7, lazy-loading, angular-universal, angular-cli-v7

I have an existing CLI project with angular version 7. I need to set up server-side rendering for SEO and social share meta tag use.

I follow the official guide given in https://angular.io/guide/universal and also take some help from a git repository https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering.

I installed all NPM modules and follow the steps as per the above two links but when I try to building bundle using below command

`ng run web:server`

It gives me an error.

Screenshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/J2d0AeGFnqt

**app.server.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {ServerModule} from '@angular/platform-server';
import {ModuleMapLoaderModule} from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

import {AppModule} from './app.module';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

@NgModule({
 imports: [
   // The AppServerModule should import your AppModule followed
   // by the ServerModule from @angular/platform-server.
   AppModule,
   ServerModule,
   ModuleMapLoaderModule // <-- *Important* to have lazy-loaded routes work
 ],
 // Since the bootstrapped component is not inherited from your
 // imported AppModule, it needs to be repeated here.
 bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

**app.routes**

```
.
.
.
export const routes: Routes = [    
   { path: 'reset_password/:token', data: { title: 'Reset Password' }, component: ResetPasswordComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
   {
       path: '',
       component: LayoutComponent,
       data: {
           title: 'Home'
       },
       children: [
           {
               path: 'home',
               loadChildren: './modules/home/home.module#HomeModule'
           },
           {
               path: 'service-providers',
               loadChildren: './modules/service-providers/service-providers.module#ServiceProvidersModule'
           },
     ]
},
];
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

My lazy load modules are not working with angular universal.
Please let me know if anyone had observed this issue before and any idea.

Comment: you have to change your import statements paths to a relative path,

like you have to change `import ... from 'src/app/...'` to `import ... from './relative path'`

Comment: You mean in app.module ?

Comment: no, in the whole application where you are getting `cannot find module` error

Comment: @Kinjal Thank you so much. I am successfully able to create a build. Now when I try to run server build it give me some "HTMLVideoelement is not defined" error. see : https://www.screencast.com/t/4tpAlls1csV

Comment: Without code I can not figure out what is the issue, but Can you please check where you used HTML video tag there might be some error